# Jar gets blocked after putting all permission attribute in manifest file

Tags: permissions, executable-jar, jarsigner

I have a jar file and its manifest file looks like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Implementation-Vendor: bothers inc.
>   Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: * 
>   Application-Name: brocode
>   Permissions: all-permissions 
>   Created-By: 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
>
> Name: Swingbro$3.class SHA1-Digest: wmSTk1O6Hh0RG1BgxkB7gkIwy58=
>
> Name: Swingbro$1.class SHA1-Digest: wrMTywvCe1Rphm6H4pb/wJNtR1A=
>
> Name: Swingbro.class SHA1-Digest: 1TJ+45M3kOEHdiHJCfORn89SxZg=
>
> Name: Swingbro$2.class SHA1-Digest: 249ntZ47KPSzzM1PnyKUVlz/Nlo=

This jar runs some .exe file. when it was trying to do so it was throwing an exception of permission attribute is missing in jar. so i added Permissions attribute to all permission but after that the jar execution is being blocked by jws( yes i am using jnlp to execute this jar which will execute an executable ie .exe) the source server is added to the exception list as well and jar is also signed with a code signing cert which has ca installed in java key store and client machine and browser.

am i missing something after adding permission attribute to the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

When running a Jar through a JNLP the the value of permission attribute in java manifest file should be same as the permission attribute in jnlp file.
JNLP file should be like:

```
 <security>
    <all-permissions/>
 </security>
Manifest should have:
Permissions: all-permissions
```